# Not receiving device id after App Update - FCM Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We upgraded our app push notifications from GCM to FCM (Firebase)

We are facing a particular problem in fetching Phone Device ID's for most of our installed user devices.

As users Update our existing App from Playstore, We stop getting Device ID's for most of the Devices which were available for the previous version. (50% and above users)

Further,

If we ask the same user to Uninstall the existing app built & then fresh install the built from PlayStore, then we start receiving the Device ID's from same phone.

Any idea of help here!

Comment: Are you referring to the [Firebase Instance ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId)?

Comment: Yes, it's the unique ID by which Firebase recognizes each of the devices. We internally call it Device ID.